# UWP: a Binding raises an issue outside Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, null, uwp

I have developed an **UWP app** that is currently in test through the Store. I encounter a strange problem: **a basic Binding seems to be "lost" randomly** when opening a page that contains some PivotItems.

The problem **occurs randomly** when the app is launched **outside of Visual Studio** (if I relaunch a version built from Visual Studio, or if I use the Store version):

- at the opening of the page, the **SelectedValue** of the **ComboBox** "***Order Type***" seems to be null:

[image: OrderType is null]

- while the **ComboBox** contains the **ItemSource** "***CoreOrderType***":

[image: CoreOrderType is present]

=> in this short video, we can see that the problem occurs randomly: [outside VisualStudio](https://youtu.be/rbXXfjxX77s)

The problem **never occurs** when the app is launched **from Visual Studio**:

[image: OrderType is present]

=> in this short video, we can see that the problem never occurs: [from VisualStudio](https://youtu.be/8hZgNx5Ciy8)

Here is the relevant code from my project:

**ViewModel - properties:**

```
private Car_Forms _carForm;
public Car_Forms CarForm
{
    get { return _carForm; }
    set
    {
        this._carForm = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CarForm);
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<V_Core_Order> _vCoreOrders;
public ObservableCollection<V_Core_Order> VCoreOrders
{
    get { return _vCoreOrders; }
    set { Set(ref _vCoreOrders, value); }
}
```

=> ***CarForm*** is the **"root" object** of my page, and ***VCoreOrders*** is the list attached to the **ComboBox**

**ViewModel - constructor:**

```
public DetailsViewModel(Guid id)
{
    // Messenger 
    Messenger.Default.Register<SendImageOnDetailsViewModel>(this, message =>
    {
        ...
    );

    // RelayCommands
    this.SaveSubmitFormCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveSubmitForm);
    this.SaveAsDraftFormCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveAsDraftForm);
    this.DeleteFormCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteForm);
    ...

    // Sync
    _synchronisation = new Synchro.Synchronization();

    // Load Car_Forms
    LoadDatas(id);
}
```

=> the ***LoadDatas()*** method loads the details of the form and the lists used for **ComboBoxes** and **AutoSuggestBoxes**

**Model - Car_Form:**

```
private string _core_order_type;
[MaxLength(200), NotNull]
public string core_order_type
{
    get
    {   return _core_order_type; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _core_order_type)
        {
            _core_order_type = value;
            if (value != null || value != string.Empty)
                core_order_type_error = false;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => core_order_type);
        }
    }
}
```

**Page - XAML**:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4,8,20,0" >
    <TextBlock x:Uid="DetailsMachineTextBlockCoreOrderType" />
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CoreOrderType}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding CarForm.core_order_type, Mode=TwoWay}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              />
    <TextBlock Text="Debug - Order Type" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CarForm.core_order_type, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock x:Uid="DetailsCommonTextBlockRecquiredField"
               Style="{ThemeResource FieldErrorTextBlockStyle}" 
               Visibility="{Binding CarForm.core_order_type_error, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

***=> Would you have any explanation? How could I debug this?***

When I place a breakpoint in the Setter of ***core_order_type***, the value is never null under Visual Studio. But I don't know a way to log this info easily outside of Visual Studio...

**Edit 1 - x:Bind**

It seems that replacing "classic Binding" with "compiled Binding" solves my problem.

But I encounter others problems on some ComboBoxes:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ProductType}"
        SelectedValue="{x:Bind ViewModel.CarForm.product_type_id, Mode=TwoWay}"
        DisplayMemberPath="description"
        SelectedValuePath="product_type_id" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        />
```

Cause the property is "nullable":

```
private int? _product_type_id;
public int? product_type_id
{
    get
    {   return _product_type_id; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _product_type_id)
        {
            _product_type_id = value;
            if (value != null)
                product_type_id_error = false;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => product_type_id);
        }
    }
}
```

The error message is: "Invalid binding path 'ViewModel.CarForm.product_type_id' : Cannot bind type 'System.Nullable(System.Int32)' to 'System.Object' without a converter"

***=> How to fix this?***

Comment: When a combobox `ItemsSource` is set with Binding to `SelectedValue`, it will show items only when `CarForm.core_order_type` matches item from `CoreOrderType`. If you see your setter, you are saying if it is not null, then process something. Assuming that it might be null, when bound, item will definitely not show up in combobox. If you want it to show up everytime,  since this is just string, set the string to `Core Order` when it is null.

Comment: But the problem isn't directly linked to the ComboBox: I have added a TextBlock which is also binded to "core_order_type". In my videos, you can see that fs this TextBlock is filled, the ComboBox is filled too.
Concerning my Setter, it must accepts null values, cause it is possible to reset all fields of the form, including the "core_order_type".